# how do I fix Segmentation fault error in assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler, att

I'm creating a 64-bit Linux program. This is my code to form a triangle. There are 3 conditions. a + b > c, b + c > a, c + a > b. I got an error 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'. Can you explain what I miss and how to fix it?

```
.data
.res: .string "%d \n"
.global main

triangle:
    movq %rsi, %rax # a
    addq %rdi, %rax # a + b
    movq %r8, %rdx # c
    cmpq %rdx, %rax # a + b : c
    jle false

    movq %rdi, %rax # b
    addq %r8, %rax # b + c
    cmpq %rsi, %rax # b + c : a
    jle false # b+ c <= a

    movq %r8, %rax # c
    addq %rsi, %rax # c + a
    cmpq %rdi, %rax # c + a : b
    jle false # c + a <= b

    movq $1, %rax
    retq

false:
    movq $0, %rax
    retq

main:
    movq $3, %rsi
    movq $3, %rdi
    movq $6, %r8
    call triangle

    movq %rax, %rsi
    movq $.res, %rdi
    xorq %rax, %rax
    call printf
```

Comment: Try running your program under a debugger and seeing what happens when it crashes.

Comment: Only thing I see here that could segfault is passing garbage into printf() - unless your segfault is because it is not running the above code.  Debug it with a debugger to be sure.

Comment: On MacOS `movq $.res, %rdi` should be `leaq .res(%rip), %rdi` . Your code is in the `.data` section which will cause problems. You need to put code in the `.text` section. `_main` doesn't have a `ret` to end it and the calls to `printf` need to be on a 16 byte aligned boundary. To fix that `main` could have the first instruct as `pushq %rbp` to align the stack on a 16-byte boundary. Then just before the `ret` in main you would do `pop %rbp`

Comment: I'm a bit surprised though that `main` and `printf` works on MacOS. Usually you have to put an `_` at the beginning like `_main` and `_printf`. If it works fine, but I am just surprised they don't cause undefined references.

Comment: Thanks. When I put the .text, it runs!

Comment: Are you sure you are assembling and running this in MacOS. It smells awfully like you are logged into a Linux system and assembling and running this code

Comment: Oh, yeah you're right. I'm using the macOS, but I'm logged into a linux.

Comment: Ok, then this is Linux code, not MacOS.  The code you write on the Linux system has *nothing* to do with what machine you logged in from.